# How can I lose the drunkard trait?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I died and now I am playing as my son who has the drunkard trait. Is there a way for me to lose this trait, like joining a medieval version of AA?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but as of version 1.1 it doesn't seem so.

I did a text search on the game's script files which describe all the interactions, events, decisions etc. in the game (`\Crusader Kings III\game\common\`) for the string `remove_trait = drunkard` and received 0 results. I then did a search just for `drunkard` to see if there is maybe a different syntax for removing a trait. I found a lot of results which check for that trait's existence or add it, but none which seem to remove it.

So apparently the one enemy you can not defeat in CKIII is alcohol.

Comment: Most of the stress-induced traits are permanent, aren't they? Indeed, almost all traits are if you're not still a child.